# Invalid use of member

Tags: c++

I want to call a field of an array in static function `dayInMonths()` but the compiler told me "Invalid use of member `Date::m_months` in static function". I have no idea :( what I doing wrong.

.h

```
class Date
{
public:
    ..
    Months* m_months;
    ..
public:
    Date(..,unsigned int months=0,..);
    ~Date();

public:
    static Days daysInMonth(unsigned int days);
};

class Months
{
public:
    unsigned int m_months;
    unsigned int m_monthsArray[13];
public:
    Months(unsigned int months = 0);
..
```

date.cpp

```
Date::Date(unsigned int days, unsigned int months, unsigned int years)
{

    ..
    m_months->m_months = months;
    ..
}

Days Date::daysInMonth(unsigned int days=0){
    return m_months.m_monthsArray[days];
}
```

months.cpp

```
Months::Months(unsigned int months)
{
    m_months = months;
    m_monthsArray[0] = 29;
    m_monthsArray[1] = 31;
...
```

Comment: `m_months` is a member of any given instance of the `Date` class. The static function `daysInMonth` gets called *without* an instance. Which `m_months` do you think it is acting on? Maybe you want `daysInMonth` to take a `Months*`, or to be a non-static member function.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you want `daysInMonth` to be a *static* function?  From everything you show, it shouldn't be.

Comment: okey, u have right, i need like this "Months* m;  return m->m_monthsArray[days];" but i get the memory adress. i know this are basics of c++ but -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static memeber function don't have `this`. And this line

```
return m_months.m_monthsArray[days];
```

is equivalent to

```
return this->m_months.m_monthsArray[days];
```

But `daysInMonth` is a static function. A static member function is shared by all instances of the class and **can access only** the names of `static members`, `enumerators`, and nested types of the class in which it is declared

You should not make `daysInMonth` static if you want it to operate on non static members.

---

```
public:
    Days daysInMonth(unsigned int days);
```

Now it can operate on members based on the object it belongs to.

---

Generally if you don't have static member variables, then you probably don't need a static member function (*except for the sake of encapsulation*).

Comment: thats the reason why i use a static function: int feb = Date::daysInMonth(2);

Comment: @user2372976 I don't think I understood. What is the reason for making it static?

Comment: okey let me thinking about the usage of static and non static functions :D